# Reminding user to complete particular task(s) in Windows 7 before PC shuts down?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, reminder

Is there a way that Windows 7 can remind me (with a dialog box for example) to complete some particular tasks before shutting down, such as locking my secret files and logging out from some services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have logon auditing enabled (which you can do from the Security Policies management console, `secpol.msc`), you can use the event viewer to find the event for user logoff or system shutdown. Then, you can click on "create a task for this event" and create a task that displays the desired message. As mentioned in the comments, you could also use a logoff or shutdown script.

If you were to use a logoff script, you would want to create the script, most likely using VBscript, and then use group policy settings (`gpedit.msc`) to set it up. The main function you'll be looking at is `MsgBox`, which displays a standard Windows message box with whatever text, buttons, icons, etc. you want.

This is just an example, which shows a warning-style box with a single OK button. For full documentation, see the [MSDN article on MsgBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(VS.85).aspx).

```
MsgBox "Please make sure to clean up after yourself before logging off. Have you done everything?",48,"Clean up"
```

...which gives you

[image: Clean up warning]

Comment: +1 He could use a user logoff script or a shutdown scipt as an alternative.

Comment: Indeed, that would work as well.

Comment: Hmmm, logoff or shutdown script, does that mean i have to write .bat file or are there other ways to do this work... (I only know about .bat files)

Comment: It would be better to use a VBscript, since those can create messages. I'll edit my post to include an example.

Comment: FYI secpol.msc isn't included with Win7 Home Premium or less.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Task Scheduler, and create a task. In the Triggers section, click New... and in the Begin a Task... drop-down, select the option that works best for you.

There a lot of different options etc. to choose from. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the wonderful option, but i can't see any shutdown trigger there.. Can you please explain more if there is any of that option

Comment: Good point. I don't see any "shutdown" option either. Perhaps you could create a task that gets triggered using the Lock function that does the things that you want, and then executes a shutdown when complete. So instead of explicitly shutting down your PC, just click the Lock instead.